# Building Grails application with bamboo using Git tag

Tags: git, tags, continuous-integration, bamboo

Currently using bamboo version 4.1.2 build 3103 and from my testing bamboo does not support buidling via Git tag. There is currently and open atlassian ticket regarding this issue

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-13618

But I want to confirm that this is still an issue or is there a work around?

So we are using the flow outlined here

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

So we are dependent on tags for our production releases but dont want to spend a lot of time investigating if tag is not supported in any format.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, use a script task as part of the 'stage and jobs' to change the branch to a  production tag

```
/usr/bin/git describe
/usr/bin/git checkout v1.2
```

Ongoing ticket to support tags in bamboo;
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-13618